# Searching through JSON and displaying results in a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to search through a JSON file and display the JSON objects that matches the country I search for, is it possible to do it in a similar way to this?

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<h2 style="text-align:center">Search</h2>
  <input type="search" id="mySearch" placeholder="Country" style="width:50%">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" style="width:50%">Search</button>


  <div class="matches" id="results"></div>

  <div class="res">
    <div class="data" id="score"></div>
    <div class="data" id="type"></div>
    <div class="data" id="country"></div>
  </div>
```

And my JavaScript files looks like this

```
var data = [{[{
   "score": 3,
   "type": "type",
   "country": "Norway",
 }..etc
}];
```

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySearch").value;
    var matches = 0;

    for (var i in data) {
        if(x == data[i].country){ //Check if data match the search
          matches += 1; //Add 1 to the number of results per result
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML ="Results: " + matches; //Make number of matches a string and send to html
          console.log(data[i].score);
          document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + data[i].score;
          document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = "Type: " + data[i].type;
          document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = "Country: " + data[i].country;
        }
    }
  }
```

While the `console.log()` shows every result and the variable "matches" displays the correct number, the HTML page only shows the last result. How can I fix this?

Comment: What `JSON` are you talking about? The `data` object?

Comment: What is expected result? You overwrite `innerHTML ` of those elements every iteration which is why you only see last one

Comment: well I hope your JavaScript file does not look like that because it is invalid.

Comment: @nick-zoum yes I'm talking about the data object. I'm sorry if it wasn't clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice that you want to start coding, love when the community grows!
As previous comments say. The innerHTML overwrites the fields. What the comments don't suggest though is a solution to your problem. So here is a suggestion. You can use the `createElement()` to create new HTML tags and append it to the DOM.

Good luck and happy coding!

```js
var data = [
  {
   "score": 3,
   "type": "type",
   "country": "Norway",
 },
  {
    "score": 5,
    "type": "type2",
    "country": "Sweden",
  },
  {
    "score": 9,
    "type": "type2",
    "country": "Norway",
  },
]; 

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySearch").value;
    var matches = 0;

    for (var i in data) {
        if(x == data[i].country){ //Check if data match the search
          matches += 1; //Add 1 to the number of results per result
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML ="Results: " + matches; //Make number of matches a string and send to html
          console.log(data[i].score);
          var score = document.createElement("DIV");
          score.innerHTML = "Score: " + data[i].score;
          document.body.appendChild(score);
          var type = document.createElement("DIV");
          type.innerHTML = "Type: " + data[i].type;
          document.body.appendChild(type);
          var country = document.createElement("DIV");
          country.innerHTML = "Country: " + data[i].country;
          document.body.appendChild(country);
          
        }
    }
  }
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">Search</h2>
  <input type="search" id="mySearch" placeholder="Country" style="width:50%">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" style="width:50%">Search</button>


  <div class="matches" id="results"></div>

  <div class="res">
    <div class="data" id="score"></div>
    <div class="data" id="type"></div>
    <div class="data" id="country"></div>
  </div>
```

A suggestion/good practice is to write functions for repetitive tasks. For example, you could write a function for creating elements like this

```
function createElement(label, data) {
  var element = document.createElement("DIV")
  element.innerHTML = label + ":" + data
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```

This way you could replace this code:

```
var score = document.createElement("DIV");
score.innerHTML = "Score: " + data[i].score;
document.body.appendChild(score);
```

with just:

```
createElement("Score", data[i].score)
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. When I try to apply a background to "DIV", all of the lines have gaps without a background between them. Is it possible to add a class to each search result, so the gaps only appear between search results and not each line?

Answer (score 0):

AS charlietfl told, you are overriding the value of you div content on each iteration of your loop.

Build the score, type and country using a string and them put the result string into the innerHTML